# "My" namespace has disappeared, and other weirdness

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently having to use someone else's login on this PC, basically because I'm the guy who replaced him at the company, and he's now living somewhere on another continent, and nobody can get this project he was working on to set up on any other machine...

Anyway, I'm trying to access the "My" namespace, and it's missing *everything* except "Settings", "MySettings" and "Resources". Obviously lacking all of this stuff sucks and I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me how to get it back...

I've looked in Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices and all the references seem to be there, by the My namespace itself isn't working right.

Another thing that's not working is the ''' XML documentation function. Normally, typing those apostrophes in the right place spawns a big mass of UML commenting for Intellisense entries but now, nothing.

I've tried both of these from my user account on the same PC and they work fine; presumably it's something my predecessor has inflicted onto his own settings in VS2010.

Does anyone know how I can fix this and go back to using Visual Studio as I know and love it?

EDIT: I got sick of this behaviour and decided to move over to my username, where I'd verified the My namespace was fully working.

Turns out that the problem reoccurred once I'd gotten the project working under my username, so it's presumably a project setting which has been turned off somewhere, as starting another project still creates an environment where "My" and the ''' comments work, but the problem project still doesn't have either feature.

Does this ring any bells for anyone?

EDIT2: Just discovered that the Visual Basic [sample code for MSDN Magazine's MVVM article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mag200902MVVM) suffers from the broken XML documentation issue, but not the My. namespace issue.

Just updating this question in case that new information rings a bell with anyone...

Answer (score 2):

Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings???

Comment: Sounds good enough to me. God only knows what he's done to this poor program.

Comment: Nope, hasn't fixed either problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to enable the application framework in the project properties (Project properties -> Application tab -> Enable application framework)

---

EDIT

Here's another possible solution: in the solution explorer, show the hidden files ("Show all files" button). In the Properties folder, select the Application.Myapp file, and open its properties. Check that the Custom tool is "MyApplicationCodeGenerator"

Comment: No, nothing. It was already enabled, and turning it off and on again didn't fix it.

Comment: Actually, it turned out that I didn't have an "Application.myApp" file before I clicked that tickbox off and back on, and putting it there wrecked the application to the point where it was crashing somewhere with no source code to show. Rather than continuing with this investigation, I'm going to stop poking the scary code-dragon with my pointy stick and instead go and hide somewhere safe where the terrible, terrible things that my predecessor hid in this project can't find me anymore. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First reset the settings as Fermin suggested and then uninstall and reinstall VS.